# how do I print this correctly in java?

Tags: java

This is my java code

```
public class exercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 8;
        int y = 4;
        System.out.println("x + y = " + x + y);
        System.out.println("x * y = " + x * y);
        System.out.println("x + x + y =" + x + x + y);

        double z = x / y;
        System.out.println("z = " + z);
    }
}
```

it's supposed to look like this:

```
x + y = 12
x * y = 32
x + x + y = 20
z = 2.0
```

but when I run it with eclipse this is the result I get:

```
x + y = 84
x * y = 32
x + x + y =884
z = 2.0
```

As you can see `8 + 4` definitely `!= 84`
As well as `8 + 8 + 4 != 884`

It looks like the eclipse typed the values 8 and 4 in the first line, and didn't add them together, the same thing with the third line it just typed 8 and 8 and 4, not adding them together.

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: `a + b + c`, when `a` is a `String` causes **both** `b` and `c` to also be `String` (to perform the concatenation). Use `a + (b + c)`

Comment: Take out the part about octal in the duplicate answer, and the explanation is the same.

Comment: `System.out.printf("x + y = %d%n", x + y);` also would work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to put brackets around arithmetic operation

```
System.out.println("x + y = " + (x+y)); 
System.out.println("x * y = " + (x*y)); 
System.out.println("x + x + y ="+( x+x+y));
```

Comment: Putting brackets is only required when there is addition. For `System.out.println("x * y = " + x*y);` bracket is not required.

Comment: Correct.But I think for readability purpose its good to put :)

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). `Not all questions can or should be answered here. Avoid trying to answer questions which have already been asked and answered many times before.`